# UnitofWork [aspnetboilerplate] Transaction Management

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6, aspnetboilerplate

I am currently working on implementing aspnetboilerplate's transaction management

Below is the method I am using to insert a order and products associated with the order

```
public class OrderController
{
    IOrderAppService _orderAppService;
    public OrderController(IOrderAppService orderAppService)
    {
        _orderAppService = orderAppService;               
    }
    public void TestOrder()
    {
        _orderAppService.TestTransaction();
    }
}


public class OrderAppService : IOrderAppService
{
    //repositories are injected here

    public void TestTransaction()
    {
        //Created 'order' and 'products' here

        //Committing the created objects
        CommitOrderTransaction();

    }

    private void CommitOrderTransaction()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
        { 
            //Inserts the Order record
            CommitInsertOrderHeader(); // Order Header is saved in database by using SaveChanges() method

            //Inserts the Product records associated with OrderId
            CommitInsertOrderDetails(); 

            unitOfWork.Complete();                
        }
    }
}
```

As the aspnetboilerplate documentation tells that,
"if current unit of work is transactional, all changes in the transaction are rolled back if an exception occurs, even saved changes."

In my case when an exception occurs on inserting the OrderDetails, I would like the header record to be rolled back as well but I still have the Order header record in database.

Comment: Do you receive the exception on client side?

Comment: Yes, I had an invalid value to one of the property in OrderDetails records resulting in 'EntityValidationErrors' on client side

Comment: What's your ABP version?

Comment: ABP - 1.5.0.0  @aaron

Comment: Woah. Could you upgrade to v2.3.0?

Comment: Would upgrading to V2.3.0 resolve this issue?
Could you help me with an example of the solution in the latest version?

Comment: I can't say for sure. But that's the only way to know the problem still exists. There have been many enhancements and bug fixes since then. The effort will definitely be better spent upgrading than trying to figure out why this innocent-looking code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to handle transaction manually. ABP handles it for you! All application service methods are automatically set as UnitOfWork. It's an atomic operation. So if any exception occurs in the middle of transactions all the db operations are being rolled back.

further information check out https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling SaveChanges() twice and you aren't using a TransactionScope across both, then you won't be able to rollback the first call.  I don't know what UnitOfWork is doing here, but if the DbContext you are working with isn't being used in that UoW, then nothing is going to happen.  DbContext is technically its own Unit of Work already.  You should be adding Orders and Order Details to the same DbContext and calling SaveChanges() just once.  Then you'd be able to roll back both in that scenario.

Comment: What if i need to use SaveChanges() in 'OrderHeader' first to get the 'OrderId' and use it for inserting the records in the 'OrderDetails' table ?

Comment: EF should take care of that for you if you hooked the FKs up correctly.  When you save both as new and the order details references the header class directly, EF will know how to deal with that.